# jQueryUI detect when element is dragged

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to detect when an element is being dragged.  The jQuery documentation states that adding a `.bind('drag'` should do it.  Unfortunately that's not working in my case.  I've verified that my item is draggable (init'd by jQueryUI).

```
//all of these elements show a "drag" listener, yet nothing happens     
console.log($('#roster .sponsors li, #roster .players li'));

 $('#roster .sponsors li, #roster .players li').bind('drag', function () {
      $('.team div.sponsors, .team div.players').remove();
      $(this).unbind('drag');
 });
```

I'm trying to get the "drag sponsor here" div tag to go away when they start dragging.... http://jsfiddle.net/gEuZz/2/

**update**

Check out this problem -- REMOVED --

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`sortstart` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-start).  You'll also want to bind the event using the same selector you used to create the sortables.  Here's a fork of your fiddle with these changes - http://jsfiddle.net/Bs6u7/.

Comment: Take a look at the link I posted above... I'm having an odd issue there I can't figure out.